# How to cut out transparent background?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have this image:

[image]

And, would like to cut out the transparent background like this:

[image]

Using PIL it would be:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image")
im.getbbox()
im2 = im.crop(im.getbbox())
im2.save("result")
```

But, how to do this using an OpenCV variant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much the same idea as in Pillow:

- Load image using the [`IMREAD_UNCHANGED`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80aeddd67043ed0df14f9d9a4e66d2b0708) flag to maintain the alpha channel.
- Get the bounding box within the alpha channel, determined by the non-zero pixels.
- [Crop the image by proper Numpy array indexing](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html).

```py
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('h62rP.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(im[..., 3])
im2 = im[y:y+h, x:x+w, :]
cv2.imwrite('result.png', im2)
```

The resulting image looks exactly the same as the one provided.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
Python:        3.9.6
PyCharm:       2021.2
OpenCV:        4.5.3
----------------------------------------
```